# How to compress json request data in browser?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, json

I want to send a some large json data from browser to our server (around 40KB).

Is there any methods that I can compress it in javascript, and decompress it in Ruby on Rails?

I was doing this because when the client connection is slow, it takes around 20 seconds to send the POST data from client to our server.

Am I doing it in a wrong way?

Comment: You can try this [cjson.js](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/cjson.js) or [Stevehanov Blog](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=104)

Comment: Closed as off-topic? Seriously? Haters gotta hate...

Answer (score 1):

For server-side: https://rubygems.org/gems/rjson

For client-side: https://github.com/dogada/RJSON

Comment: thanks. I just tried and rjson does't give me any compression for my data. I think my data schema in doesn't suite for rjson.